# \gls in the subscript has too normal size

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, glossaries, subscripts, dvi

Let us compile the following code with latex+dvips or latex+dvipdf (there are various reasons for using the DVI format; in my case, it's recompiling and adapting the old code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{nonnegativeNat}{name={N}, sort=n0, description={The set of nonnegative integers.}}
\begin{document}
\[\gls{nonnegativeNat}\ \bigcup_{j\in\gls{nonnegativeNat}}\]
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

What we see is the the size of N is the subscript is not small (as it should be) but normal:

[image: the result of compilation]

Now, page 3 in the manual `glossaries-user.pdf` says:

> If you use the DVI format, you will encounter problems where you have long hyperlinks or hyperlinks in subscripts or superscripts. This is an issue with the DVI format not with glossaries. If you really need to use the DVI format and have a problem with hyperlinks in maths mode, I recommend you use *glossaries-extra* with the `hyperouter` and `textformat` attributes set to appropriate values for problematic entries.

Here, Nicola probably does not mean the subscript problem, but refers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399515/108682. Unfortunately, there is no example of how to actually take care of subscripts, and `hyperouter` is probably a typo (I searched for `hyperouter` in the manuals for glossaries and glossaries-extra and did not find it). Any hint of how to actually get scriptsize N in the above example? I don't care that the hyperlink is actually present in the subscript/superscript positions, but I do care that `\gls{nonnegativeNat}` always prints the right letter in the right size, and that `\printglossaries` actually prints the page of the occurrence of the subscript.

Most likely related: [How do I get references in subscripts to be the right size when compiling to dvi with hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25900/how-do-i-get-references-in-subscripts-to-be-the-right-size-when-compiling-to-dvi) ,
http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7765, https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/46.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the `hyperref` package, rather than with `glossaries`: indeed, after `\newcommand*{\N}{\href{http://www.example.com/}{\ensuremath{N}}}`, we see that, _e.g._, `\bigcup_{j\in\N}A_j` yields the same problem (and can be fixed with @egreg’s trick of using `...\in\text{\N}...` as well).

Comment: Sorry, it should be `hyperoutside` not `hyperouter`. I'll correct it in the glossaries user manual.

Answer (score 3):

You can give `hyperref` some help; anyway, since this is a math symbol, it should be treated as such, hence `\ensuremath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{nonnegativeNat}{
  name={\ensuremath{N}},
  sort=n0,
  description={The set of nonnegative integers.}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\gls{nonnegativeNat}\cup\bigcup_{j\in\text{\gls{nonnegativeNat}}}A_j
\]

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LeonMeier As the manual says, this is a limitation of DVI format (more precisely, of specials understood by `dvips`). If I compile the same with `pdflatex` after removing `\text`, the size is right and the link is OK.

Comment: Of course, the `description` shouldn’t include the final period.

Comment: @GuM True, I didn’t even look at it