# Good habits: using \ensuremath to typeset math in text mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, text-mode

All of this question is about `\ensuremath` command. I would like to know, possibly from expert users, if there are any counter effects in using math commands in the text via `\ensuremath` and whether comprehensibility can be affected when using too many math symbols in this way.

If there are any issues, what is the usefulness of `\ensuremath` command? When am I supposed to use it and what's is proper application? I mean if it was thought just to use every math commands in text mode I would `\renewcommand` all math mode like

```
\let\oldalpha\alpha
\renewcommand{\alpha}{\ensuremath{\oldalpha}}
%lot of \let after
\renewcommand{\beta}{\ensuremath{\beta}}
\renewcommand{\gamma}{\ensuremath{\gamma}}
%... AND SO ON AND SO ON
```

so that I would have no more troubles in forgetting `\(...\)` or `$...$` around.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro

Comment: I would not use it at all

Comment: note if you do decide to use it, don't do `\renewcommand{\alpha}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}` as that defines `\alpha` in terms of `\alpha` so will put tex in an infinite loop.

Comment: As with everyone else, I think this is a bad idea, the `$..$` gives a much clearer sematic markup separation between the text and the math.

Comment: Assuming this could work, you would likely be tempted to type `\alpha-\beta` without math mode. Don't do it.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399707/4427, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36593/4427 or the whole list https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5Censuremath%22+user%3A4427