# Typesetting \gls in subscripts and superscript in the right size

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, glossaries, glossaries-extra, dvi-mode

Continuing [\gls in the subscript has too normal size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399705), running a loop of `latex` followed by `makeglossaries` till stabilization on

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}%%% glossaries-extra internally loads glossaries, and glossaries according to its documentation should be loaded after hyperref.
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{nonnegativeNat}{name={$\mathbb{N}$}, text={\mathbb{N}}, description={The set of nonnegative integers.}}
\newcommand{\nonnegativeNat}{\gls{nonnegativeNat}}
\begin{document}
\[\nonnegativeNat\]
\clearpage
\[\mathbb{N}^{\nonnegativeNat}\]
\clearpage
\[\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}^{\nonnegativeNat}}\]
\clearpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: second page of the DVI output] with [image: third page of the DVI output]

on the second and third pages of the DVI file and, after running `dvips`,

[image: second page of the PS output] with [image: third page of the PS output]

on the second and third pages of the Postscript file.

Clearly, the normal size of a superscript and a supersuperscript is bad, so we follow http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399707 and adapt the solution to the major engines:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}%%% glossaries-extra internally loads glossaries, and glossaries according to its documentation should be loaded after hyperref.
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{nonnegativeNat}{name={$\mathbb{N}$}, text={\mathbb{N}}, description={The set of nonnegative integers.}}
\ifTUTeX%%% xelatex and lualatex produce PDF only
  \newcommand{\nonnegativeNat}{\gls{nonnegativeNat}}
\else
  \ifpdf%%% for pdflatex
    \newcommand{\nonnegativeNat}{\gls{nonnegativeNat}}
  \else%%% for latex
    \newcommand{\nonnegativeNat}{%
      \mathchoice%
      {\gls{nonnegativeNat}}%
      {\gls{nonnegativeNat}}%
      {\text{$\gls{nonnegativeNat}$}}%%% or {\gls*{nonnegativeNat}} if we can tolerate the absense of the links but still want the page number
      {\text{$\gls{nonnegativeNat}$}}%%% or {\gls*{nonnegativeNat}} if we can tolerate the absense of the links but still want the page number
    }
  \fi
\fi
\begin{document}
\[\nonnegativeNat\]
\clearpage
\[\mathbb{N}^{\nonnegativeNat}\]
\clearpage
\[\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}^{\nonnegativeNat}}\]
\clearpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The result seems to be fine (except the blue color and the underlining, which we unwillingly tolerate in the DVI file because we use the DVI output for debugging only):

[image: second page of the DVI output] with [image: third page of the DVI output]

on the second and third pages of the DVI file and, after running `dvips`,

[image: second page of the PS file] with [image: third page of the PS file]

on the second and third pages of the Postscript file.

The solution via, essentially, nested conditionals seems a bit cumbersome for a user and rather easy for a package. Can this solution be simplified so as to get the same effect? If so, how? Why hasn't this solution (or an equivalent one) been implemented already in the combination of hyperref with glossaries-extra? Any potential issues with `\text{$…$}`?  Any potential issues with `\gls*{…}` (except we lose the hyperlinks in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, i.e., in subscripts, superscripts, double subscripts, and double superscripts)? Is there, perhaps, already a command that automates our big conditional?  We don't wish to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I copied your initial file into a file se.tex on my machine, ran xelatex se, then makeglossaries se and xelatex se again and the PDF showed the desired output. Likewise with pdflatex The problem appears to be restricted to using latex and DVI output. Any particular reason why you’re taking this course? PDF output is far more widely supported than DVI output.

Comment: @DonHosek Of course the issue is restricted to `latex`& `dvips` (a path sometimes used for recompiling legacy documents). For the other compilation paths via `{xe|lua|pdf}latex`, we don't wish to insert useless commands (say, `\text{$…$}`) or drop functionality (say, using `\gls*{…}`). Sometimes, a document is prepared to be compilable with all four engines `[xe|lua|pdf]latex`, and we don't wish to lose the ability to compile with any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find both glossary entries and links in superscripts definitively odd and for a real solution I would look for options to disable `\gls` and the links there.

Beside this: on the dvips route hyperref has to calculate the size of the link area and at least at the time when the code was written that required to put the content in a box. This freezes the size and as the box is reused the typesetted result is too large in superscripts. You can try to use the content directly in math mode but be aware that the size of the link area is then wrong, and that the content is then typeset twice, which can have side effects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\ifcsname pdf@rect\endcsname 
 \patchcmd\pdf@rect{\expandafter\box\pdf@box}{\ifmmode #1\else \expandafter\box\pdf@box \fi}{}{\fail}
\fi 
\makeatother

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}%%%
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{nonnegativeNat}{name={$\mathbb{N}$}, text={\mathbb{N}}, description={The set of nonnegative integers.}}
\newcommand{\nonnegativeNat}{\gls{nonnegativeNat}}
\begin{document}

{\[\nonnegativeNat\]}
%\clearpage
\[\mathbb{N}^{\nonnegativeNat}\]
%\clearpage
\[\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}^{\nonnegativeNat}}\]
%\clearpage
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! Concerning *odd*: typical usages would be `\bigcup_{i\in\nonnegativeNat} A_i`, `\limsup_{n\to\MyInfinity} f(n)` or `\bigcap_{x\in\MyNontrivialSet} f(x)`, where we'd wish to define `\nonnegativeNat`, `\MyInfinity`, and `\MyNontrivialSet` in the glossary. Surely, it's a matter of taste whether all such occurrences (including those in the subscripts) have to be hyper-linked, so I thought of also disabling such links via `\gls*` (which then produces the right size in subscripts and superscripts) instead of using `\gls`.

Comment: Also, I don't observe the vertical black bar to the left of your first (i.e., upper) ℕ. In my viewers xdvi, gv, and evince, I don't see this bar.

Comment: On your small example, I don't see issues with the content being typeset twice. On big examples, I recall that some PDF viewers in zooms around 100% make the certain text of TikZ nodes that is typeset twice **bolder** than it should be. As for your patch: is it possible to restrict this to the particular glossary entry nonnegativeNat and leave other glossary entries, should they be present in the document, be typeset as usual?

Comment: the content is only typeset twice (once when stored in the box and once when printed), but not printed twice. You could replace the `\ifmmode`  by your own boolean that you set to true whenever you don't want the box.

Comment: the bar is my cursor, it has a tendency to interfer with screenshots.