# New math command with alternative definition for inline mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'm interested in writing a command which would result in output that varies when called within `$...$` tags and when called within, say, `displaymath` environment.

For instance, assume that I want to define `\xnorm` command which works as

```
\newcommand{\xnorm}[1]{\|#1\|}
```

when called in the inline mode and which works as

```
\newcommand{\xnorm}[1]{\Big\|#1\Big\|}
```

when called in the "usual" math mode. How to achieve this?

I know that there exists a control sequence like `ifmmode`, but it tests whether I am in any type of math mode. Are there any more specific control sequences? Or, is there any other solution?

---

Question answered. The goal can be achieved with `\mathchoice` command. An example code snippet can be found below, in the answers to this post. Thanks all very much.

---

Nevertheless, it is worth a warning to others who have ideas similar to mine that math layout generated by `\mathchoice` can differ with the original one.

For example, try the following two functions:

```
\newcommand{\xnorma}[1]{\Big\|#1\Big\|}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\xnormb}[1]{\mathchoice{\Big\|#1\Big\|}{}{}{}}
```

(the first argument of `\mathchoice` provides a definition for "usual" math mode, other arguments do not play role in this example).

Now, simply try

```
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
\xnorma{x^2}^2 \xnormb{x^2}^2
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

A difference will be visible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/is-there-a-test-for-the-different-styles-inside-maths-mode is probably of interest.

Comment: Do you want to create a set of norm "fences" that are always small when used in inline-math mode, but are allowed to grow in size *as needed* in display-math mode?

Comment: Not exactly. My editorial problem was the following. In inline mode, I usually use very short pieces of math (as everyone), e.g. a norm of vector v. In display mode, more complex expressions with norms appear, e.g. a product of norms of, say, five subexpressions with different size. If the size of each norm "fence" was adapted to height of the contained subexpression, then I would obtain a line of norm "fences" of significantly varying heights, what doesn't look good. Therefore, my idea was to fix the height of norm "fences" in display mode to some compromise height.

Comment: Thanks for providing this additional information. I'd say @egreg's solution should be more or less what you need.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you really wants this. However, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xnorm}[1]{%
  \mathchoice{\Bigl\|#1\Bigr\|}{\lVert#1\rVert}{\lVert#1\rVert}{\lVert#1\rVert}%
}

\begin{document}
A norm in text mode is $\xnorm{v}$, while in display math it is
\[
\xnorm{v}=\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert v_i\rvert
\]
\end{document}
```

The result is really ugly (and wrong):

[image]

If you change `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` with `\bigl` and `\bigr` you get a more acceptable result, but I can't see the point of increasing the fences' size.

[image]