# math vertical alignment

Tags: math-operators

I have the following command for a function:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}


\NewDocumentCommand{\Inxy}{mmmm}{
   \mathbb{I}_{#1}%
    \left(#2\middle|\begin{matrix}#4 \\ #3 \end{matrix}\right)
}

\begin{document}
 ugly:
 \begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}
  p_1 & \cdots & p_N \\
  a_1 & \cdots & a_n \\
  b_1 & \cdots & b_n \\
  \end{bmatrix}}{x}{y}=\int_x^y \prod_{i=1}^N(a_i+b_it)^{\sfrac{p_i}{2}}
  \end{equation}
better but manual and suppose that $p_1$ height is equal to x:
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Inxy}{mmmm}{
   \mathbb{I}_{#1}%
    \left(#2\middle|\begin{matrix}#4 \\ \; \\ #3 \end{matrix}\right)
}
\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}
  p_1 & \cdots & p_N \\
  a_1 & \cdots & a_n \\
  b_1 & \cdots & b_n \\
  \end{bmatrix}}{x}{y}=\int_x^y \prod_{i=1}^N(a_i+b_it)^{\sfrac{p_i}{2}}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I want to have the #4 aligned at the outer top of vertical bar and the #3 at the bottom. How can I do ?

Comment: Welcome! Please make complete example, what you like to have .. in form of small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` amd ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have just done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\Inxy}[4]{%
  \mathbb{I}_{#1}%
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle\left({#2}\bigg|\right)$}% at least \bigg
  \left(
    #2\vphantom{\usebox0}%
  \;\middle|\;
  \smash{\vcenter to \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0{
    \hbox{\strut$\displaystyle#3$}
    \vfill
    \hbox{\strut$\displaystyle#4$}
  }}%
  \right)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}
  p_1 & \dots & p_N \\
  a_1 & \dots & a_n \\
  b_1 & \dots & b_n \\
  \end{bmatrix}\!}{x}{y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\!}{x}{y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{A}{B}{C}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complete solution where the two indices (third and fourth arguments) are typeset in script style if the macro appears in text style (like for fractions).

In the example I use `center` just to place the final example aligned with the others.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Inxy}[4]{{%
  \mathpalette\Inxy@aux@i{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}}
\newcommand{\Inxy@aux@i}[2]{\Inxy@aux@ii{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\Inxy@aux@ii}[5]{%
  \mathbb{I}_{#2}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\left({#3}\right)$}%
  \sbox\tw@{\vbox{\hbox{$\Inxy@demote#1\mathstrut#4$}\hbox{$#1\mathstrut#5$}}}%
  \left(
    #3\vphantom{\usebox\z@\vcenter{\copy\tw@}}%
  \;\middle|\;
  \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@\dp\z@
  \ifdim\ht\tw@>\dimen@ \dimen@=\ht\tw@ \fi
  \smash{\vcenter to \dimen@{
    \hbox{$\m@th\Inxy@demote#1\mathstrut#4$}
    \vfill
    \hbox{$\m@th\Inxy@demote#1\mathstrut#5$}
  }}%
  \right)
}
\newcommand\Inxy@demote[1]{%
  \ifx\displaystyle#1\displaystyle\else
    \ifx\textstyle#1\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
  \fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}
  p_1 & \dots & p_N \\
  a_1 & \dots & a_n \\
  b_1 & \dots & b_n \\
  \end{bmatrix}\!}{x}{y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\!}{x}{y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{A}{B}{C}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
$\Inxy{N}{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}}{x}{y}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can it work also in not display style with smallmatrix ?

Comment: I can't understand: the matrix in the first example is not in the definition of `\Inxy`.

Comment: I mean $\Inxy{N}{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}}{x}{y}$ will be in displaystyle....

Comment: Found here use mathpalete https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/is-there-a-test-for-the-different-styles-inside-maths-mode

Comment: @BastienRoucariès So what? Unless you want also `x` and `y` to be in script style, but that was not in the requirements.

Comment: @BastienRoucariès I added an extended version

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly use a medium sized `|` via `\Bigl|` from `amsmath` or use `scalebox` to obtain arbitrary sizes.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Inxy}{mmmm}{
   \mathbb{I}_{#1}%
    \left(#2\Bigl|\begin{matrix}#4\\#3\end{matrix}\right)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `\Bigm` be  more appropriate here, and some spacing on each side?

Comment: I'm not sure, but yes with `\Bigm` it looks better, I assumed the OP is after compactness.

Comment: Not it is not the problem see my improved example

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm not sure, if I understand well what you like to achieve, but above equation use the following `\Inxy` definition which is slightly different from yours:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Inxy}{mmmm}{
   \mathbb{I}_{#1}%
   \left(#2\middle|\begin{matrix}#4 \\ \\#3 \end{matrix}\right)
}
```

(observe one more `\\`). Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Inxy}{mmmm}{
   \mathbb{I}_{#1}%
   \left(#2\middle|\begin{matrix}#4 \\ \\#3 \end{matrix}\right)
}

\begin{document}
 ugly ???
 \begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{bmatrix}
  p_1 & \cdots & p_N \\
  a_1 & \cdots & a_n \\
  b_1 & \cdots & b_n \\
  \end{bmatrix}}{x}{y}=\int_x^y \prod_{i=1}^N(a_i+b_it)^{\sfrac{p_i}{2}}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @egreg I prefer this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\Inxy}[4]{
  \mathbb{I}_{#1}
  \ThisStyle{%
    \sbox2{$\vcenter{\hbox{\oalign{\hbox{\strut\ensuremath{\SavedStyle#3}}\cr\hbox{\strut\ensuremath{\SavedStyle#4}}}}}$}%
    \sbox0{$\SavedStyle\left(#2\middle|\usebox2\right)$}
  \mleft(
    #2\vphantom{\usebox0}%
    \;\middle|\;
    \vcenter to \dimexpr\ht0+\dp0{
    \hbox{\strut\ensuremath{\SavedStyle#3}}
    \vfill
    \hbox{\strut\ensuremath{\SavedStyle#4}}
    }
  \mright)
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{matrix}}{A}{B} \\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{M}{A}{B} \\
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \Inxy{N}{M}{x}{y} \\
\end{equation}
This is Text
  $\Inxy{N}{\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}}{A}{B}$
 and $
  \Inxy{N}{M}{A}{B}$ and $\Inxy{N}{M}{x}{y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, can you explain, what is difference between your and *egreg* answer?

Comment: Please accept egreg's answer and delete this rather than reposting with only slight modification.

Comment: This a little it different because I use another package. But thanks to egreg