# LuaTeX-Looking for some relevant and simple examples

Tags: luatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a simple example of something you can do with LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-a-simple-example-of-something-you-can-do-with-luatex)

I would like to see some little programs showing the power of LuaTeX.

Comment: Looks very much like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-a-simple-example-of-something-you-can-do-with-luatex

Comment: You're right...

Comment: @projetmbc: please let us know if the question, which Joseph pointed to, helped. We would close this one then.

Comment: @Joseph: The provided [LuaTeX wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Main_Page) has some examples on it.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, I know :-) In general, the idea here is that answers are self-contained, hence linking to another question

Comment: I'll take a look at the wiki. For the post mentionned, the answers given are a bit too general.