# How to print data in pdf in callbacks?

Tags: luatex

Could you please give me at least one example of how I can print some data in the document in callbacks with pdf.print or please help me how I can insert information in any part of the document during callbacks? For example,how I can print something using finish_pdfpage callback? Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-a-simple-example-of-something-you-can-do-with-luatex help?

Comment: @JPi `tex.print` ≠ `pdf.print`

Comment: It is very important *what* you want to print with `pdf.print`.  You probably want to use `pdf.immediateobj`.

Comment: I want to print text in page_content of pdf document,when i catch callbacks,but i dont find any example,how correct to do it,because all my attempts not give any result for me. Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: In my example actualtext not added to the document,even when i tryed use pdf.print function. I next comment you will see example of my document,which not works for me. Help me please solve my problem and thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
pdf.setcompresslevel(0)
b=0
function f(a)
texio.write_nl("Value "..a)
if a=="new_graf" then
if b%2==0 then
pdf.immediateobj("/Span <</ActualText (test)>> BDC")
else
pdf.immediateobj("EMC")
end
b=b+1
end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("buildpage_filter",f,"filter")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
paragraph one

paragraph two
\end{document}

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
pdf.setcompresslevel(0)
b=0
function f(a)
texio.write_nl("Value "..a)
if a=="new_graf" then
if b%2==0 then
pdf.immediateobj("/Span <</ActualText (test)>> BDC")
else
pdf.immediateobj("EMC")
end
b=b+1
end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("buildpage_filter",f,"filter")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
paragraph one

paragraph two

\end{document}