# Showcase of LuaLaTeX capabilities/packages

Tags: luatex, examples, big-list

The Lua programming capabilities in LuaLaTeX greatly expand what is reasonably possible within `.tex` files. I stumble across examples of cool LuaLaTeX-only code and packages here and there on the net, but have yet to see a dedicated showcase of what LuaLaTeX allows one to do.

I think it would be great to put together a collection of cool LuaLaTeX snippets and packages, to help show what can be accomplished with it, encourage people to try it, and inspire people to give LuaLaTeX a shot and see what they can do with it.

So, let's have it — please submit the most impressive LuaTeX snippets and packages you've made or come across!

---

This has been closed as a duplicate of [What is a simple example of something you can do with LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-a-simple-example-of-something-you-can-do-with-luatex), however "simple example of doing something with LuaTeX" is quite distinct from "showcase of the coolest things that have been done with LuaTeX", in the same way that "showcase of LaTeX typography" is distinct from "example of simple typography  in LaTeX".

Comment: `chickenize` is always a source of good, clean fun.

Comment: Shameless plug: https://showcase.speedata.de/en/ - all with my software which is based on LuaTeX (no LaTeX though - and the input does not have anything in common with TeX)

Comment: side note, too bad if you just need Lua for **programming** tasks there's lt3luabridge nowadays. And always the classical pythontex perltex etc.

Comment: @topskip I would love to see more details about your software built on LuaTeX. Those are some great looking documents.

Comment: @MentatOfDune what kind of details are you looking for? I might provide an answer here or at the [speedata discussion page](https://github.com/speedata/publisher/discussions)

Comment: @topskip Honestly, the link to the GitHub page was probably enough. I didn't see any details or a link to a GitHub page on the showcase page. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Lua can read bytes of something such as an image file. Does not need shell escape. Then it can decide what to do, based on the presence or absence of something in the file. Obviously takes time if the file is large. My documents require that images be pre-processed to particular specs. The processor places a comment. Lua can seek the comment, and reject the image if it is not there (and throw a TeX error).